# smoothed grouped proportion plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing

I have the following data set:

```
set.seed(10)
start_date <- as.Date('2000-01-01')  
end_date <- as.Date('2000-01-10')   


Data <- data.frame(
  id = rep((1:1000),10), 
  group = rep(c("A","B"), 25),
  x = sample(1:100),
  y = sample(c("1", "0"), 10, replace = TRUE),
  date = as.Date(
       sample(as.numeric(start_date):
              as.numeric(end_date), 1000,
              replace = T), origin = '2000-01-01'))
```

With that, I create the following plot:

```
Data %>% mutate(treated = factor(group)) %>%
  mutate(date = as.POSIXct(date)) %>% #convert date to date
  group_by(treated, date) %>% #group
  summarise(prop = sum(y=="1")/n()) %>% #calculate proportion 
  ggplot()+ theme_classic() + 
  geom_line(aes(x = date, y = prop, color = treated)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = date, y = prop, color = treated)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = as.POSIXct("2000-01-05 12:00 GMT"), color = 'black', lwd = 1)
```

Unfortunately the plot is pretty 'jumpy' and I would like to smooth it. I tried `geom_smooth()` but can't get it to work. Other questions regarding smoothing didn't help me because they missed the grouping aspect and therefore had a different structure. However, the example data set is in reality part of a larger data set so I need to stick to that code.

[Edit: the `geom_smooth()` code I tried is `geom_smooth(method = 'auto', formula = y ~ x)`]

Can someone point me into the right direction?
Many thanks and all the best.

Comment: A couple things I notice: 1) you don't need two mutate calls, just put all variables in the first mutate(). 2) mess around with the date axis, that can smooth things out.

Comment: Good call re 1), thanks! Re 2): unfortunately my dates and case number in reality are really limited so I don't have leverage in that sense, I'm afraid. (Unless I don't understand correctly, then apologies and could you clarify?)

Comment: I can't look at your data right now, but all I mean is lets say the date axis is currently by day, changing it to by month, year, etc. will help to smooth the line.

Comment: Ah, ok. Yes, I unfortunately only have these ten days in my actual data set, otherwise that'd work...

Comment: Can you post your geom_smooth code? that is the answer in my opinion.

Comment: I honestly don't really know what to put in there. Was going with `geom_smooth(method = 'auto', formula = y ~ x)` But that doesn't really get me there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want by a smoothed line? You call `geom_smooth` with aesthetics, not in combination with `geom_line`. You can choose different smoothing methods, though the default `loess` with low observations is usually what people want. As an aside, I don't think this is necessarily nicer to look at than the `geom_line` version, and in fact is slightly less readable. `geom_smooth` is best used when there are many `y` observations for every `x` which makes patterns hard to see, `geom_line` is good for 1-1.

EDIT: After looking at what you're doing more closely, I added a second plot that doesn't directly calculate the treatment-date means and just uses `geom_smooth` directly. That lets you get a more reasonable confidence interval instead of having to remove it as before.

```r
set.seed(10)
start_date <- as.Date('2000-01-01')  
end_date <- as.Date('2000-01-10')   


Data <- data.frame(
  id = rep((1:1000),10), 
  group = rep(c("A","B"), 25),
  x = sample(1:100),
  y = sample(c("1", "0"), 10, replace = TRUE),
  date = as.Date(
    sample(as.numeric(start_date):
             as.numeric(end_date), 1000,
           replace = T), origin = '2000-01-01'))

library(tidyverse)
Data %>%
  mutate(treated = factor(group)) %>%
  mutate(date = as.POSIXct(date)) %>% #convert date to date
  group_by(treated, date) %>% #group
  summarise(prop = sum(y=="1")/n()) %>% #calculate proportion 
  ggplot() +
  theme_classic() + 
  geom_smooth(aes(x = date, y = prop, color = treated), se = F) +
  geom_point(aes(x = date, y = prop, color = treated)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = as.POSIXct("2000-01-05 12:00 GMT"), color = 'black', lwd = 1)
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

```r
Data %>%
  mutate(treated = factor(group)) %>%
  mutate(y = ifelse(y == "0", 0, 1)) %>% 
  mutate(date = as.POSIXct(date)) %>% #convert date to date
  ggplot() +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_smooth(aes(x = date, y = y, color = treated), method = "loess") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = as.POSIXct("2000-01-05 12:00 GMT"), color = 'black', lwd = 1)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-03-27 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).